# I am trying to connect firebase with my flutter project but unable to do so

Tags: node.js, flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication, flutter-dependencies

after following all the steps mentioned in the "Add firebase to flutter" document whenever i am trying to run "dart pub global activate flutterfire_cli" command on my terminal it automatically closes the terminal within a second.
I am stuck and cant proceed untill and unless this step is done.
Can anyone please guide me and tell me what to d next